# Page object 'wait_for_present' error without that method present

Tags: ruby, watir, page-object-gem

While running some Ruby/Cucumber code, I encountered an odd error.

While running this code:

```
def navigate_to_expense(expense)
  on_page(HomePage).click_top_tab('Expenses')
  on_page(HomePage) do |page|
    recent = "Expense: #{expense.description}"
    if page.recent_items.any? { |i| i[recent] }
      page.click_recent_item(recent)
    else
      on_page(ExpenseSearchPage) do |page|
        page.advanced_search
        page.search_my_expense(expense)
        page.open_search_result(expense)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and #click_top_tab:

```
  def click_top_tab(name)
    if element_exists?(top_tab_link(name))
      top_tab_link(name).click
      click_top_tab(name) unless on_tab?(name)
    else
      link_element(id: 'LINK_menu_services').hover
      div_element(class: 'quciklinkdropdiv_globaldirectory', id: 'dropmenu1').link_element(text: name).click
    end
  end
```

I encountered the following error:

```
When I edit the expense                               # features/step_definitions/expense_steps.rb:156
  undefined method `wait_for_present' for #<Watir::Browser:0x42d7940> (NoMethodError)
  ./features/support/env.src/team_connect_page.rb:37:in `click_top_tab'
  ./features/step_definitions/expense_steps.rb:100:in `navigate_to_expense'
  ./features/step_definitions/expense_steps.rb:157:in `/^I edit the expense$/'
  features/scenarios/expenses.feature:16:in `When I edit the expense'
```

Line 37 is the `link_element(id: 'LINK_menu_services').hover` line. As you can see, there is no `.wait_until_present` located in the code, so I assume the error is in the underlying page object code. If that is the case, I've not been able to find it among the known bugs. If it is my code, I'm utterly confused as to where it could be at?

Comment: What version of Page-Object and Watir are you using?

Comment: 6.4.1 for Watir and 2.1.1 for Page-Object

Comment: I am still having problems reproducing the issue. Can you try to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to do this. Do I just write up some code that looks at a random webpage?

Comment: I'd suggest seeing if you can reproduce the problem on your application using just the relevant Watir commands (ie remove Cucumber and Page-Object). Assuming the problem is reproducible with that Watir code, find or create a sharable page that you can run the same script against.

Comment: Ah, yes, I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not see your whole project I can not say this for certain, however it strongly looks like the error is occurring inside an initialize_page either inside HomePage or a class it is inheriting from. I would look there.

This is just a guess, but it looks like someone tried fix a race condition and accidentally put in wait_for_present instead of wait_**until**_present.

Comment: That is not in my project space at all. It's looking like this is a bug in the page object or watir code, though I haven't had a chance to try and reproduce it yet.